# Merging all columns when specifying python engine using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using a [public dataset from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ajaypalsinghlo/world-happiness-report-2021/version/2) for this.

I'm using pandas native `read_csv` to import sample data from kaggle. I also want to be able to modify the args within a function - passing in optional `skipfooter` argument.

When I pass in the `skipfooter` argument, pandas naturally reverts to using the python engine, rather than the c engine. But in doing so, my dataframe index becomes merged and I lose all but one of my columns.

**Actual Output**

```
                                        Country name
Afghanistan 2008    3.724   7.370   0.451   50.80   0.718   0.168   0.882   0.518   0.258
2009    4.402   7.540   0.552   51.20   0.679   0.190   0.850   0.584   0.237
2010    4.758   7.647   0.539   51.60   0.600   0.121   0.707   0.618   0.275
2011    3.832   7.620   0.521   51.92   0.496   0.162   0.731   0.611   0.267
2012    3.783   7.705   0.521   52.24   0.531   0.236   0.776   0.710   0.268
```

[image: see dataframe output]

**Expected Output**

```
        Country name    year    Life Ladder Log GDP per capita  Social support  Healthy life expectancy at birth    Freedom to make life choices    Generosity  Perceptions of corruption   Positive affect Negative affect
0   Afghanistan 2008    3.724   7.370   0.451   50.80   0.718   0.168   0.882   0.518   0.258
1   Afghanistan 2009    4.402   7.540   0.552   51.20   0.679   0.190   0.850   0.584   0.237
2   Afghanistan 2010    4.758   7.647   0.539   51.60   0.600   0.121   0.707   0.618   0.275
3   Afghanistan 2011    3.832   7.620   0.521   51.92   0.496   0.162   0.731   0.611   0.267
4   Afghanistan 2012    3.783   7.705   0.521   52.24   0.531   0.236   0.776   0.710   0.268
```

I've tried setting the sep and delimiter arguments explicitly, and they haven't made any difference. Have tried passing in the header row explicitly, again to no avail.

I can quite easily hardcode a solution to this based on slicing the dataframe after the import - however, it seems like there must be a more straightforward way of getting this to work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Downloads/Archive/world-happiness-report.csv',engine = 'python')
```

```
pd.read_csv(self.src_file
                                              ,names = self.columns
                                              ,skiprows = self.skip_header
                                              ,engine = 'python' if self.skip_footer >0 else 'c'
                                              ,delimiter= ','
                                              ,skipfooter = self.skip_footer
                                              ,**kwargs)
```

Comment: what is your python,pandas version? do you have any code snippet?

Comment: code_snippet :
df = pd.read_csv('Downloads/Archive/world-happiness-report.csv',engine = 'python') -- is what is producing the merged dataframe

pandas==1.0.1
python 3.7.6

Comment: Do you see the same problem with python engine also? pandas documentation clearly says that skipfooter is not supported in 'C' engine.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @RamanSrinivasan - no I don't. Although because the C engine does not support skip footer, I'm trying to dynamically change the engine depending on whether or not skipfooter has been added as an argument. The snippet above shows that even without the skipfooter argument, the dataframe still behaves in an unexpected way.

Comment: The documentation also says that 'Python' engine is more feature complete compared to 'C' engine which is faster. Is there any specific usecase, that forces you to use 'C' engine?

Just to add, please check your logic is using the right engine.

Comment: Well, deferring to the c engine is naturally faster. So for all other use cases apart from skipfooter, I'm using the c engine

Comment: Did you try reading the CSV without column names?

Comment: Yes I did and it read the file contents. Although, this is still not the expected functionality.